# Volume of hyperellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

How can I compute the volume of the hyperellipsoid corresponding to a Mahalanobis distance $r^2 = (x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$?

I'm a bit confused because the answer involves $r$:

$$V = V_{d} |\Sigma|^{1/2}r^{d}$$ with $V_{d}$ as the volume of a d-dimensional unit hypersphere. I have seen that some statements of this problem describe $V_{d}$ as:

$$V_{d} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\pi^{d/2}/(d/2)! \;\;\; \text{for d even}\\\
2^{d}\pi^{(d-1)/2}\left(\frac{d-1}{2}\right)!/(d)! \;\;\; \text{for d odd}
\end{array}\right.$$

I thought I was supposed to integrate $r^{2}$ over $r\in [0, 1]$ and the surface of a unit hypersphere, but that doesn't give the right answer. What is the right procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start with $\mu = 0$ and $\Sigma = I,$ the identity matrix. Do you know the $d$-volume of an ordinary hypersphere of radius $r?$

Comment: Same idea, really. Do you know how to derive $V_d?$ Not contract $V_d,$ that means something different.

Comment: Sure. The differential of volume in cylindrical coordinates takes the form $r^{n-1}d\Omega$ that when integrated produces $\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\frac{r^{n}}{n}$ (although now I'm not sure why you edited user1938185's answer to include the term $1+d/2$)

Comment: Now I can see that the volume of a hypersphere is $\frac 2 d \frac {\pi ^ {d/2}} {\Gamma (1 + (d/2)) } r^d$ according to Wikipedia's n-sphere article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_sphere) but the surface of a hypersphere with radius 1 is $2 \frac {\pi ^ {d/2}} {\Gamma ((d/2)) }$ in the Sphere article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) which integrated produces $\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\frac{r^{n}}{n}$. This result is confirmed by W|A: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+hypersphere

Comment: I did not notice the extra $d$ in the denominator

Comment: Meanwhile, what I meant by derive was this: knowing $V_d,$ it is difficult to find $V_{d+1}$ but quite easy to find $V_{d+2}$ by performing an integral over a disk in polar coordinates. Not widely known, but also not hard. So you get one type of behavior for odd $d,$ another for even $d,$ although they can be combined using the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Sure. I think I understand that part, however I still don't get what is the main idea here. It seems like this Mahalanobis distance is not fully accounted conceptually into the solution described by user1938185 via $\Sigma^{1/2}$.

Comment: I've looked at your answers, you seem to know what eigenvalues are. Please do some examples yourself, in low dimension $d = 2,3$ with $\Sigma$ not just symmetric, but diagonal. You can draw explicit pictures in $d=2.$ I will look at this again tomorrow. I do quadratic forms all day, this material seems automatic to me, but hard to explain when not in person.

Comment: Great. Right now, I did the case with $d=2$. I understand that the result of expanding ($x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$ is the equation of an ellipse with major and minor axis as the standard deviations. As for the eigenvalues, I expanded $x$ using $\Sigma$'s eigenvectors (with $\mu = 0$ for simplicity) and I get a sum of eigenvalues $1/\lambda_{i}$ which are the major and minor axis, except that they are given by $\sqrt{\lambda_{i}}$. Now I can see that $\Sigma$ (in this case, $\Sigma^{-1}$ is adding elements that convert a circle into an ellipse.

Comment: and that's great but I'm a bit dissatisfied by the question itself. Maybe I thought there was more to it or I could approach it in a more formal way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ellipsoid is the transformation of the sphere of radius $r$ by the linear transform of matrix $Σ^{1/2}$.

The volume of the sphere of radius $r$ in an $d$-dimensional space is $V = \frac 2 d \frac {\pi ^ {d/2}} {\Gamma ( d/2) } r^d = V_d r^d$. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere). Note the $r^d$.

Your get the volume of the ellipsoid by multiplying with the determinant of the linear transform, which is exactly your formula.

Comment: Oh, that makes it so easy. Yes, that was the first approach I tried but I didn't know this ellipsoid was a  linear transformation of the sphere of radius $r$ using $\Sigma^{1/2}$. How can I see that? I was under the impression that I needed to work with the Mahalanobis distance.

Answer (score 4):

You can put $r$ on the right hand side: $1 = (x-\mu)^T(r \Sigma^{1/2})^{-2} (x-\mu)$. Then the answer becomes clearer:
$V = V_d\ \det(r\Sigma^{1/2}) = V_d\ \det(\Sigma)^{1/2}r^d$.