# Volume of $\{(x-\mu)^T S^{-1} (x-\mu) ≤ c^2\} = k_p |S|^{1/2} c^p$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume, variance, ellipsoids

This is following in multivariate analysis book.

The coordinates $x^T=[x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_p]$ of the points a constant distance $c$ from $\bar x$ satisfy
$(x-\bar x)^T S^{-1} (x-\bar x) = c^2 $

When $p=1$, $(x-\bar x)^T S^{-1} (x-\bar x) = (x_1-\bar x_1)^2/s_{11}$ is the squared distance from $x_1$ to $\bar x_1$ in standard deviation units.

When $p=2$, the equation defines a hyperellipsoid centerd at $\bar x$. It can be shown using integral calculus that the volume of this hyperellipsoid is related to $|S|$. In particular,

Volume of $\{x: (x-\bar x)^T S^{-1} (x-\bar x) ≤ c^2\} = k_p |S|^{1/2} c^p$

where the constant $k_p=s \pi^{p/2} \Gamma(p/2)$

I understood when $p=1$. But I don't understand the equation of volume when $p=2$.

I don't know why it changed **from equality to inequality** and **the reason (or process) for the equation to be established**. Please explain it so that I can understand.

Comment: For me, it's two ways to define the same thing, just like for a ball vs. a sphere: is somebody says "volume of the sphere", you will think that it means the volume "delimited by the sphere". Besides see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/332391

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage. $$ \{(x-\mu)^T S^{-1} (x-\mu) ≤ c^2\} = k_p |S|^{1/2} c^p $$